# LabelingFunction in BarChart displays bar-values below x-axis

Tags: visualization, labeling, charts

I'm trying to visualize some data using a `BarChart[]` in Mathematica.

The data should be placed (centered) inside the bars - except the bar is too small. In this case the date should be written above the bar.

My command for creating the BarChart:

```
BarChart[{
  {0.123, 0.492}, {2.865, 0.055},
  {1.03, 1.084}, {4.282, 0.053}
  }, AxesLabel -> {"", "Value"},
 ChartLabels -> {
   Placed[{
     "data1", "data2", 
     "data3", "data4"
     }, {{0.5, 0}, {0.8, 1.2}}, Rotate[#, (1.75/7) Pi] &], 
   Placed[{"", ""}, Above]}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#1, {{0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.5}}, 
     Rotate[#, 0.5 Pi] &] &), 
 ChartLegends -> {"⌀", "σ"}]
```

and the result:
[image]

As you can see the 1st., 4th and 8th value are even below the x-axis.

Is there some way to add some kind of 'exception' for this kind of bars?

Comment: If you just want to modify bar charts occasionally, you can just double click on a label and move it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A small change to the `LabelingFunction` seems to do the trick:

```
BarChart[{{0.123, 0.492}, {2.865, 0.055}, {1.03, 1.084}, {4.282, 0.053}},
   AxesLabel -> {"", "Value"}, 
   ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"},
     {{0.5, 0}, {0.8, 1.2}}, Rotate[#, (1.75/7) Pi] &], 
     Placed[{"", ""}, Above]}, 
   LabelingFunction -> (
     Placed[Rotate[#, 0.5 Pi], If[#1 > 0.5, Center, Above]] &),
   ChartLegends -> {"⌀", "σ"}
]
```

[image]

For now, the term 0.5 (the smallest bar size that can have a label inside) needs to be set manually.

Comment: I made a couple of changes; hope you don't mind!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Fine. It's  clearer this way at the cost of not being able to fine tune the positioning.